# Protein Pathways, Superfamilie, Function database/website?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology

I'm going trough some old data - but I'm running into this problem that all website we used use is not existing anymore.
What I have is a very long list of proteins with accession number (refSeq from NCBI) and the organism that they are from.
So where do I go to for:
1) Finding information on which pathway they are involved in. It would be great to a visualization of the whole pathway as well.
2) There function.
3) Super-family

Answer (score 0):

The **UniProt** KnowledgeBase ([UniProtKB](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/)) is the **central hub** for the collection of functional information on proteins.